# Maintaining changes to android source

Tags: version-control, android-source

If I have to change the source code of an app(Email, Browser, etc) for some custom requirement, I wonder how I should maintain the changes so that I can upgrade to the newer version of the app later when it's available.

I can thinking of maintaining the diff patch and applying to the newer version later but I am wondering if there are any best practices.  Is it good to just fork off a branch and keep merging the newer changes into it?

Thanks.

Comment: What source control system does the project use?

Comment: I am referring to the apps from android source, so it would be git I believe (android.googlesource.com or github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sony several times described their process. Here is the links:

1. http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/07/25/explaining-the-software-upgrade-process-and-its-improvements-for-android-4-3/
2. http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/12/07/ice-cream-sandwich-from-source-code-release-to-software-upgrade/

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the disciplines that:

1. Keep your modifications aside from the original code as much as possible - this will save your effort if you have to do merge code later
2. Record your modification work in an appropriate way, you need to know why you made these changes and how you did it.
3. Don't expert to do a simple merge since the changes might not be fast-forward. Rebase your repository first and pick your changes and apply carefully.

Comment: Robin, thanks for the response.  I am wondering if this is the process followed by android OEM vendors when they customize the android apps.  You are suggest to keep the modifications separate, so I guess we can maintain the "diff" and apply to the newer version of the app's source whenever it's available.  How is this effort different from doing a merge into a fork?